# Swift: Show UIView when button with segue is clicked

Tags: swift, button, uiview, segue

I try to show a UIView when a button is clicked, but it seems that the UI can't get updated, because the button also activates a segue. When I delete the segue, the UI is updated and my UIView is drawn.

Can anyone help me on how to solve this problem?

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
    if identifier == "mySegue" {
        if(myLocation == nil) {
            /* Rest of code */
            return false
        }
        else {
            // These properties need to be set
            box.hidden = false
            actInd.startAnimating()
            return true
        }

    }
    return true
}

@IBAction func startComputing(sender: UIButton) {
    //When I put the properties, nothing happens, 
    //but something like print("Button pressed") does happen.
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your `@IBAction` is directly linked to segue?

Comment: The segues goes from the button to the new View Controller. `@IBAction` is linked to this same button.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the view is within the view controller window hierarchy, so I'd do this without using segues:

```
@IBAction func startComputing(sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.transitionWithView(self.yourView, duration: 0.5, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {
    }, completion: nil)

}
```

This will present your view when the button is clicked. Inside the block you can do the rest like updating UI etc.

Comment: what you gonna animate?

Comment: This doesn't work. The idea is to show the UIView 'box' and UIActivityIndicatorView 'actInd' when the button is clicked (in the current View Controller). When the computations are done, the segue leads me to the new View Controller and sends the computed data (this works already).